# Showing the evaluation map is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

This question comes from my linear algebra textbook, and I'm a little lost. Took an attempt at it, but I'm a bit confused. If someone could lead me to the right direction, that'd be great.

Define the evaluation map as follows:
$v_a: C^{0}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$

$f \mapsto f(a)$

We are asked to show that $v_a$ is a linear transformation, and to describe ker($v_a$).

Can someone help me understand what the evaluation map is, and how the fixed $a$ plays a part in this, as well as some hints to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: The evaluation map maps a function ($f$ in $C^0(\mathbb R)$) to its value at $a$ ($f(a)$ in $\mathbb R$). For example, for the function $f(x)=x^2$, we have $v_a(f)=a^2$.

Comment: It's confusing stuff! When defining the evaluation map the role of the function and its input switches. You now think of the input as defining a function on the space of functions. It can take awhile to get used to this. You might want to look up currying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Hint: $(f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a)$ by definition of addition of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Define $v_a : C^0(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $v_a(f) = f(a)$. Then

$$ v_a(f + g) = (f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a) = v_a(f) + v_a(g),$$

$$ v_a(cf) = (cf)(a) = cf(a) = c v_a(f).$$

Now

$$\ker(v_a) = \{f \in C^0(\mathbb{R}) : f(a) = 0\}.$$

**Question:** Is $v_a$ surjective? If yes, what can I do here?